# popen and output of system command

Tags: c, arrays, linux, popen

I have to figure out the available space in /mnt/ in my application. I wrote the following code. However, execute_cmd some times returns junk apart from the actual output. For ex: 4.5K(followed by junk). Where am I going wrong? Could some one review and let me know why execute_cmd returns a junk byte at the end? How do I improve the code?

```
char *execute_cmd(char *cmd)
{
        FILE *fp;
        char path[100];
        int ii = 0;
        //char ii = 0;
        char *buffer = malloc(1024);
        char len = 0;

        /* Open the command for reading. */
        fp = popen(cmd, "r");
        if (fp == NULL) {
        printf("Failed to run command\n" );
        exit(1);
        }
        printf("Running command is: %s\n", cmd);

        memset(buffer, 0, sizeof(buffer));

        do {
        len = fread(path, 100, 1, fp); /* Is it okay to use fread? I do not know how many bytes to read as this function is a generic function which can be used for executing any command */
        strcat(buffer,path);
        printf("Number of bytes is: %d\n", len);
        } while (len != 0);

        len = strlen(buffer);
        printf("Buffer contents are: %s %d\n", buffer,len);

        /* close */
        pclose(fp);
}

void main()
{
        char *buffer = "df -h  | grep \"/mnt\" | awk '{ print $4}'"; /* FIXME */
        char len;
        char units;
        float number;
        char dummy = 0;
        char *avail_space;

        avail_space = execute_cmd(buffer);
        len = strlen(avail_space);
        units = avail_space[len - 1];

        printf("Available space is: %s %d %c end here\n", avail_space, len, units);
        number = strtof(avail_space, NULL);
        printf("Number is: %f\n", number);
}
```

Comment: It would be much more efficient to just use `statvfs()`...

Comment: What's read by `fread()` is not usually null terminated — but you assume it is.  Also, you use what was read by `fread()` the time before on EOF, because you don't check that `fread()` succeeded until after you use the path information.  Top-tested loops with assignments (`while ((len = fread(…)) != 0)`) are better for I/O.

Answer (score 1):

`sizeof(buffer)` is `sizeof(char*)`, which is probably 8 (or maybe 4). So your `memset` only clears a little bit of `buffer`. But with your use of `fread`, it's not just `buffer` that needs to be cleared; it's the temporary `path`.

Uninitialized local variables like `path` are not zero-initialised. You could use `memset(path, 0, sizeof(path));` to clear it -- here the `sizeof` works because `path` really is an array -- but simpler is to initialise it in the declaration: `char path[100] = "";`.

Since `fread` does not NUL-terminate what it reads, there might be arbitrary garbage following it, making the `strcat` Undefined Behaviour. In fact, the `strcat` is totally unnecessary and a waste of cycles. You know how much data you read (it's in `len`) so you know exactly where to read the next chunk and you can do so directly without a temporary buffer and without a copy.

For future reference, if you are planning on calling `malloc` and then using `memset` to clear the allocated region, you should instead use `calloc`. That's what it's there for.

Comment: Also, you don't return anything from the function execute_cmd().  You should return(buffer)